# Scoping assignment and local, bound and global variable in R

Tags: r, function, variables, global-variables, local

I am new to R and trying to figure out behavior of local,bound and global variables. I am confused with the following problem. If I write the function in the following way, then what are the local, bound and global variables of function f?

```
f <- function(a ="") {
  return_a <- function() a
  set_a <- function(x)
      a <<- x
  list(return_a,set_a)
}
```

Comment: Well, there are no global variables in R so that part of the question is easy. Variables are in environments, and functions (closures actually) look first in the environment in which they are defined.

Comment: So, is there any local variable in f? I mean how should we classify return_a and set_a ? I am confused mostly because of the use of <<- which can change everything even after calling f.

Comment: Note that you don't call the functions `return_a` and `set_a` (you need to add parentheses to call them, e.g. `return_a()`), which might contribute to the confusion.

Comment: So, my confusion is because, say 
`p <- f("Justin")`
`p$set_a("Carl") `
Would change the ouput of `p$return_a( )`

Comment: That's because you're doing exactly that - `set_a()` uses `<<-` operator, which looks outside of its scope and changes `a` there. If you then `return_a()`, then `a` is obviously changed. That's why it's suggested to almost never use `<<-` operator.

Comment: Does that imply both return_a and set_a are not local variable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return_a` is a function. `set_a` is a function. They are both functional objects (with associated environments, but using the word "variable" to describe them seems prone to confusion. If you call `f`, you get a list of twofunctions. When you create a list, there are not necessarily names to the list so `p$set_a("Carl")` throws an error because there is no `p[['set_a']]`.

```
> p <- f("Justin"); p$set_a("Carl")
Error: attempt to apply non-function
```

But p[[2]] now returns a function and you need to call it:

```
>  p[[2]]
function(x)
      a <<- x
<environment: 0x3664f6a28>

> p[[2]]("Carl")
```

That did change the value of the symbol-`a` in the environment of p[[1]]:

```
> p[[1]]()
[1] "Carl"
```